# Is there a way to force Android Studio to use JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME in the "Project Structure | JDK Location" dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-home

Locations for the Android SDK, Android NDK, and JDK are specified here in Android Studio.

[image: Project Structure Dialog]

I'd like to leave the "JDK location" field blank (or something like that) so Android Studio uses the "JAVA_HOME" and/or "JDK_HOME" environment variables instead. However this results in an error at the bottom of this dialog stating that a valid JDK path must be specified.

I've tried putting %JAVA_HOME% and $JAVA_HOME$ into the dialog box for "JDK location" but they don't work (i.e. same error message at the bottom).

The reason I want to do this is because we develop across multiple PCs and anytime there's a Java update we have to manually remember to update Android Studio as well.  If everything would use the environment variables, updates would be much smoother.

Comment: Try using `$System.env.JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Nope, that still results in "Please choose a valid JDK directory." at the bottom of the dialog.